# Facebook Graph API - Place Distance Inaccurate

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to use Facebook Graph API to retrieve a set of places at a certain coordinate.

Using the API, I executed the following query:

https://graph.facebook.com/search?access_token=APPTOKEN&type=place&center=3.187501,101.627542&distance=50000&limit=500

Theoretically, this query should return 500 places within 50km of that coordinate. However, it only returned some 15 results that are within the immediate vicinity (say few hundred meters) of that coordinate. I tried changing the distance to 10000, 5000 or even 1000, while tweaking the limit parameter to figures such as 50, 100, 1000 but the total results remain the same.

There are certainly other places nearby, i.e. if I change the query's coordinates to the following location which is less than a kilometer away, it returns a whole new result set:

https://graph.facebook.com/search?access_token=APPTOKEN&type=place&center=3.192022,101.625647&distance=50000&limit=500

Can someone please advice if my query is problematic, or that Facebook's Graph API is somehow limiting the distance or total results?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that you only get 15 places in that kind of search was a bug on Facebook.

This bug has been solved today so your query should work better now (I actually tried and it does). Anyway [here](https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/236950866472021/) you can see more details about this bug.

What I personally don't know is this: Now your query returns around 450 results, if you limit it to 5km instead of 50km is still more or less the same amount of places.

I tried queries with different distances and coordinates, seems to me that Facebook limits your total amount of results so you never have more than around 450 places.
Even using pagination (with an offset) I can't manage to get more results (and I know there are more than 500 places within 50km around New York...)

So if you find the answer to this I would be interested ;)

Comment: Thank you, the 15 places limit is lifted, but like you mentioned, there is still an upper limit imposed on each query and the pagination does not work for those exceeding the 400+ results. I think this is intentionally done by Facebook to limit result spidering/caching, making you query them in real time for location-based data.

Comment: Now there seems to be a limit at 7 results :(

Comment: Same behavior in 2016, consistently getting 448 places

Answer (score 0):

I am encountering a similar problem, I have built a tool to return geo-locale results based upon keyword, city/state (or zip code) and radius up to 30 miles. What used to work flawlessly up until early December 2013 started to return only 15 results in late December. My "educated guess" is that FB is limiting results to prevent people like you and me from turning a profit from this information!!!

Comment: Yes, I came to the same conclusion. The only way is to query in real-time for the search results, and if coordinates are not specified, the choices are very limited due to the minimal results. Facebook should've updated their API to state the limitations rather than have developers crack their heads thinking its our own bugs!